# GWT Bootstrap3 Openlayers offline

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, gwt, openlayers, offline

I am using GWT with Bootstrap3 and Openlayers Map. I have implemented my own OSM Map server.
My application does not start without internet connection. I need guidance.

I followed the instructions in boostrap3 V1.0.2 for offline applications.
However I only got a blank screen.

Starting with the Firefox debugger I got the following message in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: OpenLayers is not defined
    <anonymous> http://www.openstreetmap.org/openlayers/OpenStreetMap.js:7
```

Starting with Google Chrome I get the following warning

```
[Deprecation] Application Cache API manifest selection is deprecated and will be removed in M85, around August 2020. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6192449487634432 for more details.
```

followed by

```
GET http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
```

and

```
localhost/:1 Application Cache Error event: Invalid or missing manifest origin trial token: http://localhost:8090/simaso/simasoweb/appcache.manifest
```

Here is my basic setup

SiMaSoWeb.gwt.xml:

```
...
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.json.JSON'/>  
  <inherits name="com.google.web.bindery.autobean.AutoBean"/>  
  <inherits name="org.gwtbootstrap3.extras.cachemanifest.Offline"/>  
...
  <add-linker name="offline" />
```

SiMaSoWeb.html:

```
<!doctype html>

<html manifest="simasoweb/appcache.manifest">
  <head>
    <title>Sirene</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="simasoweb/simasoweb.nocache.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.openstreetmap.org/openlayers/OpenStreetMap.js"></script>    
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="SiMaSoWeb.css">
....
</html>
```

In ...\simasoweb\appcache.manifest I find:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# Version: 1599380329409.0.6297069797290025

CACHE:
AF4477772D0DB53A10ABCF74A5AE0C4D.cache.js
fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff
clear.cache.gif
fonts/FontAwesome.otf
css/bootstrap-notify-custom.min.cache.css
7192594CA2F468C2F793523022719FA0.cache.js
...
css/font-awesome-4.7.0.min.cache.css

NETWORK:
*
```

Finally
I compile all this . Resources seem to be included in the war file ..
Needless to say that with internet connection, only in the first 1-2 seconds of starting, all is running fine ..

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Google Chrome warning](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6192449487634432) you included, App Cache is a deprecated standard and is being removed. It has already been removed from non-secure contexts.

You should be using Service Workers instead to cache resources for offline use. You may have to write your own linker or maybe you can use [gwt-serviceworker-linker](https://github.com/realityforge/gwt-serviceworker-linker).

Comment: I added gwt-serviceworker-linker. The necessary code was placed right at the start of onModuleLodad routine. I had to include element2.dom and element2.promise libraries. Compiling is fine - no errror. However I failed on the proper <inherits ...> statement, e.g. Loading inherited module 'com.google.elemental2.Elemental2'
         [ERROR] Unable to find 'com/google/elemental2/Elemental2.gwt.xml' on your classpath

Comment: That's not the right module name. You can see the GWT module names in [the Elemental2 documentation](https://github.com/google/elemental2). They are like this: `<inherits name="elemental2.core.Core"/>`, `<inherits name="elemental2.promise.Promise"/>`,  `<inherits name="elemental2.dom.Dom"/>`  (I'm not sure which modules you need, but these are my guess). If you continue to have problems, ask a new question as this is a different topic from the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ELEVATE I managed to move from AppCache to ServiceWorker. However the Openlayers couldnt be fixed this way. So here is what solved the issues:

ServiceWorker

1. I am still using Java 8
2. I upgraded to GWT 2.9
3. I added to .gwt.xml

   ```
   <inherits name="org.realityforge.gwt.serviceworker.Linker"/>
   <inherits name="elemental2.dom.Dom"/>
   <inherits name="elemental2.promise.Promise"/>
   <inherits name="jsinterop.base.Base"/>
   ```

...
and

```
  <add-linker name="serviceworker"/>    
  <extend-configuration-property name="serviceworker_static_files" value="./"/>
  <extend-configuration-property name="serviceworker_static_files" value="../SiMaSoWeb.html"/>
```

In my entry JAVA-routine right at the start of my onModuleLod I added

```
import static elemental2.dom.DomGlobal.*;
import elemental2.dom.DomGlobal;

public void onModuleLoad() {
 ...
    initStatic();
 ...
```

and later in that module

```
public void initStatic() {
if ( null != navigator.serviceWorker )
{
  navigator.serviceWorker.register("simasoweb/"+ GWT.getModuleName() + "-sw.js" ).then( registration -> {
      console.log( "ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: " + registration.getScope() );

      // Every minute attempt to update the serviceWorker. If it does update
      // then the "controllerchange" event will fire.
      DomGlobal.setInterval( v -> registration.update(), 60000 );

      return null;
    }, error -> {
      console.log( "ServiceWorker registration failed: ", error );
      return null;
    } );

  navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener( "controllerchange", e -> {
    // This fires when the service worker controlling this page
    // changes, eg a new worker has skipped waiting and become
    // the new active worker.
    console.log( "ServiceWorker updated ", e );
  } );
}       
}
}
```

I had issues with accesing the right files in my gwt - war directory. Therefore I updated the navigator.serviceWorker.register... command.
Very useful was the google inherent debugger with CTRL+SHIFT+I. In the 'console'-tab you find the messages - red means bad - solve it!

As external jar libraries I had to include

```
elemental2-core
elemental2-dom
elemental2-promise
base
```

Now the openlayers issues... Needless to say that there might be a much more elegant way and further more, you need an offline-map, which I have rendered myself and available (150GB for Germany!).

4. In the HTML file

Note that I opened the openlayers and openstreetmap .js files in a browser copied them in a file and copied them into my war directory in the subdirectory src. Again the browser debugger can help find directory issues.

```
     <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="simasoweb/simasoweb.nocache.js"></script>
     <script src="src/OpenLayers.js"></script>
     <script src="src/OpenStreetMap.js"></script>
```

5. Copy hard
   I downloaded the gwt-openlayers demo project GWT-OpenLayers-master.zip
   and copied all files in GWT-OpenLayers-master\gwt-openlayers-showcase\src\main\resources\org\gwtopenmaps\demo\openlayers\public\openlayers into my ...war\src\ directory where my openlayers.js files lie.

Finally I am not sure if the service-worker point 1-3 really helped.